# Nginx Drupal rules for Views pager

Tags: 7, commerce

I just realised many guide on the internet not works for Drupal 7 Views pager

This is generally Nginx and Views pager issue. I've tried in Apache2 and the pager works without problem.

For example, I'm installing Commerce Kickstart. After submitting contents (SKU), I try to browse `admin/commerce/products`. But sadly, when clicking next page, it not showing any change

The first page URL is

```
http://www.website.com/admin/commerce/products
```

while second page, third page, and so on is:

```
http://www.website.com/admin/commerce/products?sku=&page=1
http://www.website.com/admin/commerce/products?sku=&page=2
http://www.website.com/admin/commerce/products?sku=&page=3
```

Currently, below is my nginx config:

```
server {
    server_name *.com *.net *.org *.in *.cc;
    root   /var/www/html/$host;
    index  index.php index.html;
    set $boost "";
    set $boost_query "_";
    if ( $request_method = GET ) {
      set $boost G;
    }
    if ($http_cookie !~ "DRUPAL_UID") {
      set $boost "${boost}D";
    }
    if ($query_string = "") {
      set $boost "${boost}Q";
    }
    if ( -f $document_root/cache/normal/$host$uri$boost_query.html ) {
      set $boost "${boost}F";
    }
    if ($boost = GDQF){
      rewrite ^.*$ /cache/normal/$host/$uri$boost_query.html break;
    }
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include         fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
    location ~ (.*)/x-progress-id:(\w*) {
        rewrite ^(.*)/x-progress-id:(\w*)  $1?X-Progress-ID=$2;
    }
    location ^~ /progress {
        report_uploads uploads;
    }
    location ^~ /files/private/ {
        internal;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        track_uploads uploads 60s;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the line:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
```

to:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$query_string;
```

to pass the query_string to drupal.

(see [HttpCoreModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#.24uri) for more informations about nginx variables)